# What is the difference within the compiler between debugging and running the code? (STM32)

Tags: debugging, compilation, stm32

somehow when i am running my code, it seems like one GPIO Port isn't being initialized, meanwhile if i am debugging, it is.

I am initializing two sensors:

```
struct MAX31856_t max31856_temperature_sensor_heater_1 = MAX31856_TPL( SPI_DEV_TPL( IO_PIN_TPL(
        TEMP_SENSOR_0_CS_GPIO_Port, TEMP_SENSOR_0_CS_Pin), &spi1));

struct MAX31856_t max31856_temperature_sensor_heater_2 = MAX31856_TPL( SPI_DEV_TPL( IO_PIN_TPL(
        TEMP_SENSOR_1_CS_GPIO_Port, TEMP_SENSOR_1_CS_Pin), &spi1));
```

Sensor Heater 1 is not getting any Information, Sensor Heater 2 is getting Informations. Now if i swap the Name of the Heaters:

```
struct MAX31856_t max31856_temperature_sensor_heater_2 = MAX31856_TPL( SPI_DEV_TPL( IO_PIN_TPL(
        TEMP_SENSOR_0_CS_GPIO_Port, TEMP_SENSOR_0_CS_Pin), &spi1));

struct MAX31856_t max31856_temperature_sensor_heater_1 = MAX31856_TPL( SPI_DEV_TPL( IO_PIN_TPL(TEMP_SENSOR_1_CS_GPIO_Port, TEMP_SENSOR_1_CS_Pin), &spi1));
```

and run the code in the debugger, Sensor Heater 1 and 2 are getting Informations.
How can this happen? I was thinking about a timing problem, but since it is working in the debugger, i don't really know what to do.

Comment: The debugger uses GPIOs for JTAG/SWD related signals. Perhaps your sensors are using the same pins ?

Comment: Otherwise could be due indeed to timer issues. What you break at the beginning of the debug session, your sensors may have time to start whereas they don't when you run

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you are debugging and/or running the same binary. Debugging is mostly the same as running except if you halt the processor (es breakpoints).
In that case...

- some peripherals could continue to run or be halted togheder with the cpu, the behaviour is some cases can be configured. (timers, watchdog...)
- some interrupts can be lost.
- some hardware buffers can overflow and data can be lost (if you don't use any flow control in your IO)

Answer (score 0):

How do you run the code in debug mode? Do you have breakpoints somewhere?

You (OP) are right about it being most likely a timing problem, and probably related to physical SPI transmission. Because your line of code to send/receive something over SPI has already executed in the MCU, but physically the bits and bytes are still being transmitted on the line, while MCU is already calling the next SPI function, so one of the transmissions will fail. Try adding some delay after SPI transmission code. If things work after that, then it's the timing of SPI peripheral, and you need to add a check that there is no SPI transmission already in place before you call a functions to send/receive something.

You can do `while(transmission)` (pseudocode, replace with actual check if SPI transmission is going on) to wait until the previous transmission ends to call the next one.